# unity - retrieving data from firebase database

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity-game-engine

I am new to firebase and somewhat new to Unity (also, this is my first stack exchange post). I know how to write to firebase, but I do not know how to retrieve from the data tree.

The way my data is structured (roughly) is as follows:

```
{
Users:{
    "Email": , 
    "Password":
    }
}
```

How would I access the elements of my users and retrieve such things as their email and password?

Comment: This should explain it pretty well: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#retrieving_data. Just replace the `Leaders` with the name of your node.

Comment: hi Frank. I'm still a bit confused. How would I iterate through the keys i create and access the email and password element of the said key?

Answer (score 8):

I'm in the same boat as you (new to both firebase and unity), but something like the following worked for me.  I adapted it to your scenario without testing, so might have minor bugs but it should get you started.  Perhaps someone more experienced can improve upon it.  I'm intentionally sparing details on proper handling of passwords.

```
   //assuming
         public class User {


            public string email;
            public string password;

            public User (string email, string password) {
                this.email = email;
                this.password = password;
            }
        }

    //inside some class
        public void AddUser(){
          User user = new User("email@email.com", "password");
          string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);
          Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference dbRef = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference
          dbRef.Child("users").Push().SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
        }

        public void GetUsers(){
          Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase dbInstance = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;
          dbInstance.GetReference("users").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
                    if (task.IsFaulted) {
                        // Handle the error...
                    }
                    else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                      DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                      foreach ( DataSnapshot user in snapshot.Children){
                        IDictionary dictUser = (IDictionary)user.Value;
                        Debug.Log ("" + dictUser["email"] + " - " + dictUser["password"]);
                      }
                    }
          });
```

Answer (score 4):

Ik this is an old post but it might help someone,

Just call SaveAndRetrieveData() function to save and retrieve data where ever you want

```
public void SaveAndRetrieveData() //from the database (server)...
{
    //store the data to the server...
    reference.Child("My Car Collections").Child("Sports Car").SetValueAsync("Ferrari");
    print("data saved");
    //Retrieve the data and convert it to string...
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("My Car Collections").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => 
    {  
        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
        string ss = snapshot.Child("Sports Car").Value.ToString();
        print(ss);
        print("data retrieved");
    });        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By creatively copy/pasting from the [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#retrieving_data) I get to this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
  .GetReference("Users")
  .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
    Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
    return;
  }
  Debug.Log(arg.Snapshot.Child("Email").Value)
}
```

Comment: And this will allow me to iterate through the database and check the users? when i put it in my code, all it shows me is a dictionary in my console window of changes made to my database.

Comment: You're only writing a single suer to the database, so this code displays that user. Writing a list of users involves calling `Push()` as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#append_to_a_list_of_data

Comment: yes i have that. what i am having trouble understanding is this: I have a database with multiple sets of data, i want to iterate through that data and check the user accounts in that data. the code example you gave me above shows the changes made when i add a new piece of data. the google documentation does not give me a solid understanding on how i could iterate through my list of data and compare an email entry to one i have.